# Waiting for two Observables to complete before proceeding?

Tags: java, android, observable, retrofit2, rx-java2

> I have a loading page where I want to perform two network requests (retrofit2-rxjava) for unrelated information.  I don't want to proceed to the next page until those two requests are finished, even if either one or both fail.
>
> 1. Tied the requests together using zip.  Is there a way to not be forced into using a BiFunction, and not have to return null?
> 2. Requests A and B have a .doOnNext and .doOnError.  if one of these return an error, does the zip observable continue?  and does the zip subscriber also return the error?
> 3. Is this the best way to do this?

```
private Disposable retrieveBothThings() {
return Observable.zip(getThingA(), getThingB(),
                    (A, B) -> {
                        onAllCallsComplete();
                        return null;
                    })
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(o -> {}, Logger::e);
}
    
    

private Observable<...> getThingA() {
            return SessionManager.getInstance().getApi()
                    .getA()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .doOnNext(this::onACompleted)
                    .doOnError(this::onAFailed);
}

private Observable<...> getThingB() {
        return SessionManager.getInstance().getApi()
                .getB()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
              .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).toObservable()
                .doOnNext(this::onBSuccess)
                .doOnError(this::onBFailure);
}
    
private void onBSuccess(...) {
    ...        
}
    
private void onBFailure(final Throwable throwable) {
    Logger.e(throwable);
}

private void onACompleted(...) {
    ...        
}
    
private void onAFailed(final Throwable throwable) {
    Logger.e(throwable);
}
```

Comment: If you return null you'll get RuntimeException because nulls are not accepted in RxJava2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine two observables using the `merge()` operator. You can transform an error into `onComplete()` using `onErrorResumeNext()`.

```
Completable.merge(
  observable1
    .doOnNext(this::onACompleted)
    .doOnError(this::onAFailed)
    .onErrorResumeNext( Completable.complete() )
    .toCompletable(),
  observable2
    .doOnNext(this::onBCompleted)
    .doOnError(this::onBFailed)
    .onErrorResumeNext( Completable.complete() ),
    .toCompletable() )
.subscribe( ignore -> {}, 
            error -> {},
            () -> { processCompletion(); } );
```